# How can I fix my Alienware? Software problems

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, windows-10-upgrade, help-files

I have an Alienware 18 running Windows 10.
I am having an Application Process Problem, how do I fix it?

Specs: 1TB hd, 256 ssd, Dual Nvidia gforce860's, 8GB RAM. not under warranty.

I bought the computer used and haven't had any problems with it until last night when it updated without my knowledge. I thought I had shut it down but apparently it installed an update. Though all the lights were off on the keyboard and side, it appears it wasn't, so in the Alienware backpack it went.

I get home and when I opened the screen it turned on and it said windows update 78% which means it must have been on during travel in my car.

I go to use an application and nothings working. Application Hangs, nothing is opening or running. I cant click on the start menu either. I decide to *right click* the Desktop > Properties and I got `ms-setting:display and ms-personalization-background problem`

It said

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action.

So I try right clicking on the start menu and it kind of worked. I click run cmd and it opens. I type in **sfc/scannow** and it will not allow and says to run as administrator.

*Right click* the start menu again and hit **run cmd as administrator** and my screen goes into a weird state where it looks like my desktop has a layer of opacity added, (similar to when you install a program and it prompts you to allow access to hd changes). It blurred out the desktop but there was no prompt to do anything.

5 minutes later without touching anything it returns to normal desktop. Now all of a sudden the start menu and search bar work when I *left click* them.

Turned off computer then turned it back on and held <kbd>f12</kbd>

Ran diagnostics and everything is good, battery at 89%, all tests passed.

I start it up and when it gets to log in screen I hold **shift** and *right click* the power option in the bottom right corner and hit **Restart**. It opens the windows restore screen that is blue and gives me the option to start to reset the computer or **advanced options**. I select **advanced options** and **run cmd as administrator**. It works.

I type in `sfc/scannow`, 100%, didn't find any problems.

I start it up normally. I try to click the **start menu** but it doesn't work so I *right click* and open `event viewer`. it shows a bunch of logs from me trying stuff with errors. I'm at a loss at this point, I called tech support (how I found the warranty is out) and I'm 4 hours into this. Any help would be appreciated.

---

- **UPDATE**

  ok so trying system restore failed, something was corrupted so i opted to just wipe everything and reinstall the win10 through the windows recovery environment page. I clicked the option to reset windows to its former win10 brand new version while keeping some appdata. It seemed to make the computer work but now i had to manually install the alienware command center and i can only find v3.6 not 4.0. No idea why it removed vital stuff like the Nvidia graphics card drivers either so i had to reinstall those. Went to dell.com and tried a diagnosis, and it all seems to be running smooth for now. I would however like to know what Nvidia graphics drivers or audio drivers i need to have reinstalled or where to go to get them. Same thing with any other programs you guys can think of in terms of missing items after complete wipe

Comment: Better? I formatted it to get it the proper attention. Now that it is legible how would you suggest I resolve the issue???

Comment: Thank you, now any help on resolving the problem?

Comment: It looks like it tried to install the anniversary update. If it fails in between you pretty much have a corrupted OS. You can try to install the update again or even first remove it and than add it. To be honest I just highly suggest a reinstall of the OS. Or even a refresh

Comment: I think i had set a restore point. Would that be an alternative. using the shift>restart method at the login screen? or would completely removing the OS and reinstalling be better? Or is there a way to reinstall the anniversary update. I was hoping that was the problem and not hardware problems

Comment: You could try the restore point, If it was before the update that would be your savior. But if it fails your better off reinstalling your OS this way you can make sure if its software related, If it still occurs after the installation than it is definitely an hardware issue but it sounds like a software issue. Because windows 10 is not subtle with their upgrades.

Comment: I think the restore point was Sept 29, and this problem occured between the 2nd - 3rd or fourth i think. So I can only hope

Comment: Hey Dylan, I tried using multiple restore points however i keep getting "Error, this signifies that there are some damaged/corrupt System Files which is preventing the installation of the Update". I tried the update troubleshooter and some other ones. it says it repaired damaged or corrupted files but it still wouldnt let me restore. your suggestion is to wipe everything?

Comment: Yep a complete reinstall is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing and reading through the comments, I believe there is only one real option.  A full OS reinstall as was mentioned by @Dylan Rz.

The Alienware 18 should have a Windows CD key sticker either on the bottom of the system, or included with the materials.  So if you have that, all you will need is a install disk for the OS.

As far as drivers for the system, they can be found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/alienware-18/drivers/advanced).

If you are technically saavy/inclined, and you have a desktop system, you could move the drive(s) you keep data/media on to the desktop and back up files you want to keep, then move the drive(s) back to the laptop for the OS reinstall.

Comment: I have gone through the process of a clean re-install, details can be found here regarding finalization of the restoration process if you are so inclined to read it, as I have a few more questions to fix the laptop entirely - http://superuser.com/questions/1131574/what-programs-drivers-apps-or-other-third-party-software-do-i-need-after-a-cl

Comment: You state in that post the following "Apps Removed while Refreshing your PC."

Comment: AGAIN i hit enter trying to format my comment:    @Dylan Rz made some great points.  I can honestly say some of the lack of software issues may be OS version related.  Here is a commonality:  I am now running 10 pro, and I am trying to find certain applications for my Asus Sabertooth 990fx R2.0 board that I had under 8.1, and they are not listed on the Asus website.    As far as the Alienware Command Center 4.0, following link shows only Win 7 and Win 8.1 support:  [link](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverid=JD5K1)