# What Programs, Drivers, Apps, or other third party software do I need after a clean reinstall of Windows 10?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, battery, windows-10-upgrade

Ok so I have an Alienware 18. 1TB HD, 256 SSD, Dual Nvidia 860M's, 8GB RAM.
I was having some problems the other day and have concluded that it was a corrupt OS from **Windows 10 Anniversary Update** (Aug 5 Update I think?). Please review the question posted here if you feel things are not making sense or if you disagree on what the problem was and a resolution to it - [How can I fix my Alienware? Software problems](https://superuser.com/questions/1131242/how-can-i-fix-my-alienware-software-problems)

It got messed up during installation and corrupted my OS to the point where my **Start Menu** wouldn't work I also could not use a **System Restore** point. I tried multiple restore points to no avail. I prayed it wasnt hardware problems, and after hours of exhaustive research I ended up doing a clean reinstall of windows 10 while keeping my files but it deleted all the apps and third party software.

I had to reinstall some apps for games, my *Razer* mouse, *Firefox*, *Chrome*, add ons for each (ie **Privacy Badger** and **Adblock Plus**). But surprisingly I also had to reinstall the **Alienware Command Center** and the **Nvidia** graphics drivers. I downloaded the Alienware Comand Center from Dell.com however it only gave me the option for 3.6 and not 4.0. I'm wondering if there is a compatibility issue or if i need to specifically search for the 4.0.

I also used to have a Battery Life Extender **Desktop Charging Mode** which allowed my battery to only charge above 50% to 100% in order to preserve Battery integrity however i cannot find that option anymore. I am curious if I just went to Dell.com and downloaded all their recommended drivers and programs if it will fill the missing items, or if there is a downside to that.

I have also ran a diagnostic check on the hardware both from Dell.com and from the **Control Panel** and everything has passed so I'm fairly certain it was just a bug in the Win10 Update. I had a minimal amount of data on the computer but the issue is my lingering question of "what other things would I be missing after my reinstall?" It gave a list of Apps removed while refreshing my PC however I'm not sure if it is a comprehensive and an all inclusive list. Here are some of the items I have not yet reinstalled as I do not know where to find them, and any help on identifying any other programs that might have been missed would be appreciated.

---

***Apps Removed while Refreshing your PC***

Dell System Detect - Version 7.6.0.4

Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable x(64) - Version 8.0.59192

NVIDIA 3D Vision Driver 372.90

NVIDIA GeForce Experience 2.11.4.1

NVIDIA Graphics Drivers 372.90

NVIDIA HD Audio Driver 1.3.34.15

NVIDIA PhysX System Software 9.16.0318

---

As previously stated I reinstalled the Graphics driver and the Dell System Detect, but i have yet to do the audio one or any others.

---

**Update**

So for issues regarding clarity, I want to be very specific with my questions so i get an appropriate answer.

- Will Dell.com allow me to download a driver manually, if i already have that driver?
- If Dell.com allows me to download a driver that I already have, will it create problems because of the redundancy?
- Are there any specific programs that Alienware computers come with (stock) that I should make sure i have?
- How can I find a comprehensive list of what is missing from both a driver and application aspect (as Dell.com's *Guide me* automated driver search does not do what I need it to do)?
- How do I get the Desktop Battery Charge mode available for use again? The button is currently greyed out and i cant click it

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia Drivers: http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience Install this application this will take care of all the nvidia parts

- Will Dell.com allow me to download a driver manually, if i already
  have that driver?
  **Yes you can remove the drivers and reinstall them manually**
- If Dell.com allows me to download a driver that I already have, will
  it create problems because of the redundancy? **Usually no, but its still a possibility with certain drivers**
- Are there any specific programs that Alienware computers come with
  (stock) that I should make sure i have?  **Nope**
- How can I find a comprehensive list of what is missing from both a
  driver and application aspect (as Dell.com's Guide me automated
  driver search does not do what I need it to do)?
  **Win + X Key will show up a list in the left bottom corner, then click device manager this will show the devices that do not drivers**
- How do I get the Desktop Battery Charge mode available for use again?
  The button is currently greyed out and i cant click it. **This could be a driver issue you might have installed the wrong drivers.**

Comment: I think i found out that specifically for the Desktop battery charge mode, it is under Windows 8.1 Alienware OSD, which is their On screen display driver or something like that. Someone had said they re installed that after a clean install of windows 10 and the battery desktop charge mode came back and it worked so I will try that. Also thank you for the other answers especially the win+x device driver function. Any help on navigating it and what to look for? Like in regards to devices that dont have drivers? (i think thats what you meant but typoed) Any help is appreciated and thanks again

Comment: Also Thank you Dylan you're the man, this is the 2nd time you've came and helped in clutch moments!!!! Didnt realize it was you until after haha

Comment: @jdoe Devices that don't have drives will have a yellow ! next to them it really stands out so you will know. If there aren't any then everything is working correctly.

Comment: ok, i mean after the update everything was broken, i was devastated because i thought the mandatory win10 anniversary update bricked my laptop. After the clean reinstall you suggested it seems to be working even, when i had not yet installed the NVIDIA graphics drivers though, so now my concern has shifted from working, to working with the same functions and capabilities as before. Also thanks again for your prompt, concise, informative, and clear help/instructions/suggestions.